# Entity Framework Code First Updating with Where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-5

I am using [FilteredSet](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/using-a-filtereddbset-with-entity-framework-to-have-dynamic-filtering) to have automatically data from the current logged user of my system. It provides me a dynamic way to return data from the current user and not access other users data.

I would like to do the same when I am updating an entity. I could get the entity from the database with the FilteredSet and if the entity id doesn't belong the the user thrown an exception BUT I prefer not to load the entity first and simply attach this one and update.

So far, I have try:

```
public void UpdateOwnable<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity, IUserOwnable
{
       var entityLocal = SetOwnable<TEntity>().Local.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == entityId);
       if (entityLocal==null)
       {
          entityLocal = this.SetOwnable<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
       }
       this.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Single(d => d.Entity == entityLocal).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

The problem is that the query generated doesn't include a WHERE clause. I would expect to find a way that the Where clause is not only the primary key of the entity but also the user id.

```
Update Workout
SET name ..
WHERE id = 1
AND idUser = 123;
```

This SQL query is what I would like to have Entity Framework to generate. With an "AND" clause for the idUser.

Can this be possible?

Comment: Is there a reason your not just using the .Where LINQ extension method? eg: entity.Where(x=> x.id == 1 && x.idUser == 123)

Comment: Yes, it requires to have to every developer to add this condition. If some one forget, it could be dangerous. This is why, having a dynamic way to do it is interesting because if you set your entity to me "marked" to be "owned" by a user that it will force every access to be linked to the current logged user. Here is some explication : http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/using-a-filtereddbset-with-entity-framework-to-have-dynamic-filtering

Comment: It's also not possible to add a Where clause in the Update...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF doesn't provide out-of-the-box functionality to add where condition to Update statements. You can use for example [batch update](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx) from this open source project. The difference is that your update will not be part of `SaveChanges` call (because EF doesn't support it).

Comment: The open source project looks great!